# buffer causing prior/excessive GPU error when displaying multiple lines of text in Swift ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am building an app where I wanna display multiple lines of text on my target Augmented images. The program works fine for less than 7 lines of text but crashes when it reaches more than 7 lines. I also notice if a line is too long, the same error "Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors)" also appears.

```
    let text = SCNText(string: "this is the first line  \n hello this is the second line \n hello this is the third line \n hello this is the fourth line \n hello this is the fifth line \n hello this is the sixth line \n hello this is the seventh line \n hello this is the eigth lines\n " , extrusionDepth: 0.1)

    //setting the basic properties of text

    text.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 1)
    text.flatness = 0.005
    text.isWrapped = true
    let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: text)
    let fontScale: Float = 0.01
    textNode.scale = SCNVector3(fontScale, fontScale, fontScale)
```

// setting the text to be centered above the picture and facing the camera

```
    textNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2
    centerNode(node: textNode)

    //self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
    // the text will be centered right above the image
    node.addChildNode(textNode)
    // create a plane node as the background of the text
    let textWidth = text.boundingBox.max.x - text.boundingBox.min.x
    let textHeight = text.boundingBox.max.y - text.boundingBox.min.y
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(textWidth), height: CGFloat(textHeight))
    plane.firstMaterial?.transparency = 0.5
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

    planeNode.position = SCNVector3(textWidth/2,1.5*textHeight,-0.0001)
    textNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

"Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors)"

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue when my text was creating too much complexity. I reduced the total number of polygons by increasing the `flatness` of my `SCNText` and was able to render more text.

```
text.flatness = 0.6    // default value
text.flatness = 0.0005 // more polygons, higher complexity
text.flatness = 1.0   // lower polyon, lower complexity (uglier text)
```

Try reducing complexity. Lighting, total polygon count, material complexity, etc.

Comment: I have been stuck in this bug but now it got finally solved. Thanks